# Plotting stacked bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart, with
`xaxis = 'customer_id(count)`, `yaxis = 'age_band'`,
and the 3 different loyalty groups stacked in the chart (hue), so I should see 6 bars each with 2-3 different colours.

code I've tried:

```py
df.groupby(['age_band','loyalty']).agg(Loyalty=('customer_id', pd.Series.nunique)).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Picture for reference:
[image: data frame & current bar chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
(df.pivot_table(index='age_band',columns='loyalty', values='customer_id', aggfunc='nunique')
       .plot(kind='bar', stacked=True))
```